# Why i get the error "Call to undefined function node_object_prepare()" while i try to add a node programmatically in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

i'm trying to add a node content programmatically from a custom module file. I have created the .module file and used this code as suggested:

```
$node = new stdClass(); // We create a new node object
$node->type = "page"; // Or any other content type you want
$node->title = "Your title goes jere";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or any language code if Locale module is enabled.
$node->path = array('alias' => 'your node path'); // Setting a node path
node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.
$node->uid = 1; // Or any id you wish

// Let's add standard body field
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a body text';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'Here goes a summary';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; // If field has a format,  you need to define it. Here we define a default filtered_html format for a body field

$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid
```

but when i enable the module what i get is an error saying "Call to undefined function node_object_prepare()"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to include `node.pages.inc` to be able to use this function from within your module:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

I just tried the using `node_object_prepare()` from a sample module without using the above code and it seems to work just fine. As @Clive mentioned is his comment you should add your code for creating a node programatically inside a module hook and not directly in your module file.

```
// create a node using 'hook_menu' in your module, this might not be the
// best hook for doing this but it should work
function <MODULE>_menu() {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = "page";
  $node->title = "Your title goes jere";
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->path = array('alias' => 'your node path');
  node_object_prepare($node);
  // ...
}
```

Reference: [Module hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7)

Comment: Hi Krister, thanks for the reply. I've included what you suggested but what happens is that after enabling the module now all the content of the .module file is printed in simple plain text above the header of the Drupal template and no content results created in the database, at least nothing is shown in content admin page...

Comment: `node_object_prepare()` is in node.module, so including node.pages.inc won't make a difference. Marco, I get a horrible feeling this code is directly in your module file, and not in a hook/other function? And make sure you have `<?php` at the top of your module file, obviously.

Comment: Sorry guys, ignore the plain text comment above, as an idiot i just accidentally deleted the php opening tag. That's what happens when you are distracted by a woman in bikini on the beach. Clive, yes you are right, the code is directly in module file. Sorry but i'm quite a beginner this time on Drupal. I know the hook implementation but what kind of hook i have to use for add a node this way?

Comment: @Marco - You could either add the code in a hook function or you could specify a custom function in your module and then call this function from somewhere else.

Comment: You're asking slightly the wrong question there @Marco...in what context (i.e. after what action) do you want this node to be created?

Comment: Ok i think i got it. I wrongly supposed that every hook action would be function specific. I realized i can invoke all function wrapping them in a hook. I think i will use this code in hook_enable since i want this content to be created soon as the module is enabled. Thanks a lot guys.